# Does creation of a foreign key mean creation of an index?

Tags: sql, sqlite

If I have a column `a` inside table `Foo`, and I create a new table `Bar` with a column `b` that is a foreign key to `Foo.a`, is column `b` automatically indexed for `Bar`, or must I still create an index on `Bar.b` if I want to efficiently search for all rows in `Bar` with `b = 1`?

(If it matters, I am using SQLite.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foreign keys are just used to ['force exists relationships between tables'](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html), but not automatically indexed based on their related column's index. Indexing `Foo.a` will speed up inserts/updates on `Bar.b`, while indexing `Bar.b` will speed up selects on `Bar.b`.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a Foreign Key in SQLite is only creating a constraint. You should create the index yourself.

From the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html), near the end of paragraph 3:

> So, in most real systems, an index should be created on the child key
>   columns of each foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the index yourself. At least I know no DBMS that does it automatically.

Comment: I misread the question. I thought he was asking if an index would be created on the target of the FK. :) (Or now that I read it again, maybe I didn't misread it... I don't know. I should go sleep. Either way, MySQL doing it doesn't mean it's required, just meant it as a little side note. [As for InnoDB only, that's because MyISAM doesn't support foreign keys])